# Задал условия в php

Tags: php

Задал условия в php - if и else  но, почему то  if выводится как надо по условию а else всегда выводится, что не так ? В моём случае выводится "да нет ошибся!"

```
<?php
$a=101;
if ($a > 99) {
 echo "да ";
}

 else ($a<100);
 {
        echo "нет ошибся!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: потому что нет такой конструкции как `else (условие)`

Comment: допишите if после else: `if (..) {..} elseif (..) {..}`

Answer (score 1):

Лишняя точка с запятой после `else` и еще надо писать `else if` если хотите задать условие

```
$a=101;
if ($a > 99) {
  echo "да ";
}
else if ($a<100){
  echo "нет ошибся!";
}
```

Comment: Хауди хо, не правильно научил(

Comment: @АлексейСивков лучше почитать, чем видосы смотреть http://php.su/
или вот книга в pdf https://vozhzhaev.ru/files/books/%D0%94%D1%8D%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4_%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80_%D0%98%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%A0%D0%9D%D0%A07.pdf

Answer (score 0):

у `else` - нет параметров. Если нужны параметры используйте `elseif` или `else if`

Answer (score 0):

Все понял, после else нужно ставить то что выполнится если не выполняется условие if, а если ставишь условие для else нужно писать else if()

```
<?php
$a=101;
if ($a > 99) {
 echo "да ";
}
 else    //<= поставил уловие и не написал if после else (else if) + лишние точка с запятой (;)
 {

        echo "нет ошибся!";
 }
?>
```